# Спряжение глагола "ездить"

Tags: спряжение

Как правильно в письменной и разговорной речи спрягается глагол "ездить"?

Comment: Это вопрос из домашнего задания? Если нет, то почему считаете, что правила склонения «в грамматике и в разговорной речи» не одинаковы?

Comment: Ни в грамматике, ни в разговорной речи ни один глагол не склоняется. Они спрягаются.

Answer (score 1):

[**е́здить**](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) — глагол, несовершенный вид, непереходный, невозвратный, II спряжение.
В письменной и разговорной речи глагол "ездить" правильно употреблять так.

**Настоящее время:**
1 лицо — е́зжу, е́здим;
2 лицо — е́здишь, е́здите;
3 лицо — е́здит, е́здят.

**Прошедшее время:**
е́здил, е́здила, е́здило, е́здили.

**Повелительное наклонение:**
е́зди, е́здите.

**Сослагательное наклонение:**
е́здил бы, е́здила бы, е́здило бы, е́здили бы.

**Причастия:**
е́здящий, е́здящая, е́здящее, е́здящие (наст. вр.);
е́здивший, е́здившая, е́здившее, е́здившие (прош. вр.).

**Деепричастия:**
е́здя; е́здивши, е́здив.

Это единственно правильные варианты написания и произношения слова [**ездить**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB/%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) (никаких других литературных форм нет).
Какое-либо иное написание или произношение считается ошибочным (иногда его относят к просторечным или диалектным).

Answer (score 0):

Я езжу, мы ездим.

Ты ездишь, вы ездите.

Он, она ездит, они ездят.

В разговорной речи иногда можно услышать "ездиит", "ездиют" и т. п., но это встречается лишь в речи не очень образованных, мягко говоря, носителей языка.

Comment: Вы тоже не знаете, что глаголы **спрягаются**?

Comment: Да, я в школе давно учился, что-то уже забылось :)